# Angular | How to extend a FormGroup after it has be initialized?

Tags: angular, forms, formgroups

Im writing a system in Angular6. The system uses forms, implemented with `FormGroup`.

**Question:** How can I extend the form after init?

Example:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
          'field_1': new FormControl(null),
          'field_2': new FormControl(null)});

    if (a == 'some value') {
       // Extend this.form with field_2 and field_3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a method called `addControl`:
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl

`this.form.addControl('field3', new FormControl(null));`

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to form group

```
if (a == 'some value') {
   this.form['field_3'] = new FormControl()
}
```